# Meaning of キリ型 (can’t find in dictionaries)

Tags: meaning, translation, etymology

[image: ドライバー(キリ型)で底をキレイにするわ]

Saw this term in a manga and can’t find a good explanation of what it is. The text says

> ドライバー(キリ型)で底をキレイにするわ

(底 refers to the sole of a shoe)

However, the image seems to resemble more an awl than screwdriver. I could find some mentions that キリ can mean “cross” (from Portuguese “cruz”), however プラス seems to be a far more common term for a Philips screwdriver, so that’s probably not it.

In desperation I turned to Google Translate and it offered me  “drill type screwdriver”, but while I don’t know what exactly is that, it doesn’t seem to match the picture either. So, what exactly is キリ型?

**EDIT**
To add to the fun, on the next page the “screwdriver” gets stuck in a shoe when dropped, so is it an awl after all? It seems that “awl” can be translated as 突きぎり, is this ぎりrelated?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

キリ means gimlet. 型means "type" There are some type of screwdriver. Name is different on the shape.

I don't know much about when getting stucked

キリisn't 切り(cut)

Comment: I checked on the dictionary. It is つきぎり as you said. I know キリ but I didn't know that Japanese word.(I'm Japanese.)

Comment: Thank you! So it’s not a *screw* driver, but a screwdriver-shaped tool for drilling holes? Is it common to call such tools ドライバー?

Comment: There are two type of キリ. One move by でんち(battery?) Another one used your hand. You can call it as スクリュードライバー or つきぎり.

Comment: Yes it's screwdriver shaped to drill hole.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky The "screwdriver-shaped tool for drilling holes" is called a pin vise or hand drill